# Monitoring system - asp.net, nhibernate, and ajax?

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-ajax

Let me start off by saying that I am completely oblivious about the pros/cons of using the tools I mentioned in creating a web application for a Monitoring system.

I don't even know if this is the right place to ask this; but I'm giving it a shot.

Now that that is off the table, can anyone give their thoughts on possibly a monitoring system, that will be handling sensitive data, using asp.net, nhibernate, and ajax?

I know it's a vague question. But I would really appreciate ANY kind of insight about it...

Answer (score 1):

Monitor what data ? Sure, you can use these tools. You build an asp.net site, you use ajax for async calls, and you "monitor" the data from the database with NHibernate (you could map the tables like read-only entities and with stateless session to even optimize this all), but what are your exact requirements. What are you monitoring ?

Comment: To monitor a customer transaction, where he can check its status, check whether the request has been already processed.. I guess it's something like that. Would those tools best fit a system like this?